# How to SFTP a Stream using PGP Encryption

Tags: c#, sftp, pgp, ssh.net

I am using PgpCore & SSH.NET to encrypt a stream and create a file on a remote server via sftp with the encrypted stream.

I have the below attempt, however, while I can successfully list the files in the remote directory, i can not write to a remote file. I get the error `no such file` at the `pgp.EncryptStream` line.

```
using (var client = new SftpClient(server, 22, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();
    Console.WriteLine("Connected to client.");
    var inputStream = new MemoryStream();
    var fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    inputStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    inputStream.Position = 0;

    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

    var files = client.ListDirectory("/upload/");

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        string remoteFileName = file.Name;

        Console.WriteLine(remoteFileName);
    }

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        string remoteFileName = file.FullName;

        Console.WriteLine(remoteFileName);
    }

    using (PGP pgp = new PGP())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing PGP...");
        using (Stream outputFileStream = client.Create("/upload/test.txt.pgp"))
        using (Stream publicKeyStream = new FileStream(@".\PublicKey.asc", FileMode.Open))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypting Stream...");
            pgp.EncryptStream(inputStream, outputFileStream, publicKeyStream);
            Console.WriteLine("Stream Encrypted.");

            //Console.WriteLine("Uploading File.");
            //client.UploadFile(outputFileStream, string.Format("/upload/{0}", "test.txt.pgp"));
            //Console.WriteLine("Upload Complete.");
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Exception Stack Trace:

```
   at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession.RequestWrite(Byte[] handle, UInt64 serverOffset, Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 length, AutoResetEvent wait, Action`1 writeCompleted)
   at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpFileStream.FlushWriteBuffer()
   at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpFileStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at Project.Web.Areas.Pims.Controllers.Eod.EodController.EncryptStream(String fileName, StringBuilder sb) in C:\Repos\Solution\Project.Web\Areas\Pims\Controllers\Eod\EodController.cs:line 144
```

EDIT:
For those who may find it useful, I managed to get the encrypted file uploaded using `client.OpenWrite` instead of `client.Create` as shown below. I have also added code to sign the encrypted file with my pgp Private Key and Passphrase:

**WORKING SOLUTION:**

```
using (PGP pgp = new PGP())
{
    using (Stream outputFileStream = client.OpenWrite("/upload/test.txt.pgp"))
    using (Stream publicKeyStream = new FileStream(@".\MSPublicKey.asc", FileMode.Open))
    using (Stream privateKeyStream = new FileStream(@".\PrivateKey.asc", FileMode.Open))
    {
        pgp.EncryptStreamAndSign(inputStream, outputFileStream, publicKeyStream, privateKeyStream, pgpPasspharse, true, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have edited to include the exception stack trace.

Comment: The upload folder does exist and this is confirmed when i list the directory and loop through the files. This code actually creates the file `test.txt.pgp` but no data is in it and an error occurs at `pgp.EncryptStream`

Comment: Yes that upload succeeds. I have managed to get the encrypted file uploaded now using `clinet.OpenWrite` (shown in the edit above).

Answer (score 0):

You can encrpt the file to local pc and then you can upload file to remote server

```
   string path= "c:\yourfolder\test.txt.pgp";

   using (Stream outputFileStream = client.Create(path))
    using (Stream publicKeyStream = new FileStream(@".\PublicKey.asc", FileMode.Open))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypting Stream...");
        pgp.EncryptStream(inputStream, outputFileStream, publicKeyStream);
        uploadfile(path, "/upload/test.txt.pgp");
        Console.WriteLine("Stream Encrypted.");

        
    }
```

Below method can upload the encrpted files to remote server

```
    static void uploadFile(string sourcepath, string destination)
    {
        FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read );
        byte[] bytes= new byte[file.Length];
        file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);          
        IAsyncResult result = client.BeginUploadFile(ms, destination); 
        //you can also use client.UploadFile()

       
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to avoid saving files to local drives and rather create a file purely in memory and then encrypt and send to the server. Do you know a way to do this?

Comment: please Share the code  pgp.EncryptStream() method or you can just modify it to return the encrpted stream instead of writing it to a file. then you can use the stream in uploadFile()

Comment: pgp.EncryptStream is a method from PgpCore (https://github.com/mattosaurus/PgpCore#encryptstream) which I am using to encrypt the data

Comment: can you share me pgpcore dll??